# Why does jQuery.each not retrieve the correct height value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using `$.each` in the latest version of jQuery to calculate the height of a collection of DOM elements selected by class name,

```
$.each($('.some-class'), function() {
  console.log($(this).height());
}
```

I get a list of height values which all appear to be off and higher than they should be, 640, 657, 334, 487.

However, when I enter my console and calculate the first height, `$('.some-class').first().height()`, I get `553` instead, which is accurate.

What's happening with $.each? It seems to be selecting the correct `$(this)` when I checked it with `console.log($(this))`.

Comment: When does your $.each loop execute? Are you sure all of the elements are done loading by the time the loop executes? It is possible that the height of the `.some-class` elements changes.

Comment: without any test case, it's quite hard to help

Comment: P.S. You should probably be using `$('.some-class').each(function(){`.  This isn't a solution, just a suggestion.

Comment: Given the context, it might be useful to see a an example such as in a jsfiddle that manifests this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I answered my own question. I was executing the code after the document finished loading in a `$(document).ready(function(){...})` block, which meant that the heights were being calculated after the document was finished loading, but **before** the page was fully loaded and all my other code in my `$(document).ready` block were finished loading.

When I calculated the heights after the window finished loading, in a

```
$(window).load(function(){...})
```

block, I was able to get the correct height values.

I also failed to mention that I am using Ruby on Rails in Development mode, so the assets (CSS, etc.) get compiled at runtime. My suspicion is that given the Rails asset pipeline, my CSS stylings were not being loaded by the time the HTML document was loaded and my `$(document).ready()` block was fired off, so my stylings may not have been applied yet in the time between the document was ready and my window is done loading, which then influences the heights of my DOM elements.

Calculating the DOM heights after the window was done loading in a `$(window).load` block allowed me to ensure that my CSS stylings were already applied before the heights were calculated.

Thought this was a straight jQuery question. Turned out to be a potential Rails issue.

Thanks all!

Comment: You should accept your question as correct if it indeed the solution to your question.

Comment: Yeah, but stackoverflow only allows you to do so after 2 days of posting. :)

Answer (score 0):

`.height()` always returns the content height, It won't care about css box-sizing property.
If you have or don't have `box-sizing:border-box` it does not include the padding and margin.

You can use `.css( "height" )` instead of `.height()`